# Button with keyboard input via Input Method Kit

Tags: cocoa, keyboard, input-method-kit

I am creating a virtual keyboard for my application via Input Method Kit (IMK).

However I am not able to simulate a keyboard event by pressing a button.

Is there any library I can used for keyboard event simulation?

Are there any reference materials/solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

See the [IMKTextInput Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/IMKTextInput_Protocol/Reference/IMKTextInput_Protocol.html), you need to call `insertText:replacementRange:`

```
[client insertText:text replacementRange:NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, NSNotFound)];
```

where `text` is an instance of `NSString`.